How to crop text in monogame?
I'm making a game in monogame that uses fake windows as a puzzle element. I'm able to resize the windows, and I figured out how to crop images at the edges of the window, but I can't figure out how to crop text when you resize a window.
I can't just remove each letter when they go behind the border, because:

the text is drawn after the border, and
the letters are wider than the border. I'm using the default SpriteFont class and _spriteBatch.DrawString method for my text.

Basically, I want the following code to crop the text in some way
SpriteFont font = Content.Load<SpriteFont> ("font file");
_spriteBatch.Begin();
_spriteBatch.DrawString(
    font,
    "Text here",
    Vector2.Zero,
    Color.White
    );
_spriteBatch.End();

I looked through the documentation, but couldn't find any overloads that let you crop text. Please help.

If the border is drawn before the text, you should have your window width available before drawing the text.  Use the window width value to format the text.  SpriteFont has a MeasureString method that gets the length and height for the comparison.  As far as I can tell, the approach is to remove chars from your text string until the text width is smaller than the window width.  Another option would be to paste your text to images with fixed size, then crop the images of text the same as you are doing with your other images.

@Kevin the border is only 8 pixels wide, and the font is monospace with each letter being 16 pixels wide. Also, there's a language select option, so I can't just make the text images.

So is the window a fixed size, like the border and text?  If the border and text are always the same size, then you need a blank space at the start of your strings, and then you will need to measure the string and the window and remove chars from the right end of the strings until it fits the window - border.  There is no overload for cropping text

@Kevin no, the window can be resized. I actually have 8 different fonts of 8 different sizes. The smallest one has each letter only 8 pixels wide. I know there is no overload for cropping text. I was mostly wondering if there was a better way to display text where I could crop it, or a way to automatically turn the text into an image that I could crop.

could you include how you are sizing your window, when you are drawing the border, and when you are drawing the text?

@Kevin I am resizing the window by dragging the borders with the mouse. Resizing the window already works perfectly. I can't include a code snippet, because I am away from my computer right now. I draw the text on top of the borders.

If everything is monospaced, can't you just calculate the available size in pixels and only pass the string of length Math.Min(string.length, availablesize/16)?

You probably need to look at your order of operations.  You should be able to draw the text first, and have the border drawn on top of the text, or you'll need to measure the window and the text string, and then reduce the text string size until it is less than the horizontal width of the window - border.  You should be able to draw your border and text in the same spriteBatch to control the order.

@Kevin I don't think you understand. One character is wider thaand the border width. I can't pass it a string with a percentage of a character. If I just resize the string, then it will be jittery when I resize the window. I need to be able to cut characters in half.

If you cannot control the order of operations and draw the border second, or it doesn't look right when you do so, the only other way I can think to do it with how monogame "draws" text and borders within windows is to stack two windows.  The outer window should be larger than the inner window by the size of your border, and have only the border drawn in it, and the inner window have only the text drawn in it.  The window will auto size or crop the text when you resize it, and the border will no longer be "drawn" underneath it.

@Kevin yeah, that would work. I might do that. Currently my plan is to make the string shorter at the edges, and replace the first and last letter with images, which I can crop.

There is a property on the sprite batch for a scissor rectangle, use it to specify the area which it is allowed to draw within.

There is? How do I use it? That sounds like exactly what I need
